# Why doesn't my form submit automatically?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I don't see what is wrong, does `submit()` not work anymore?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is the title</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">

        function onLoad() {
            document.getElementById("input1").value="text1";
            document.getElementById("input2").value="text2";
            document.getElementById('form').submit();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">
<form method="post" name="form" id="form" action="test.txt">
    <label for="input1">Input1</label> <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text"/>
    <label for="input2">Input2</label> <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text"/>
    <input name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your javascript console for errors

Comment: Using forms[0] instead of form's name is not a good idea.

Comment: @MK - i disagree, a XHTML-compliant page should only have 1 form (unless the script is on an external JS file, which it isnt).

Comment: @RPM no one said anything about XHTML, also in all the browsers i use `document.forms` is an array of DOM elements and there is no such thing as a 'form' object which is not a DOM object. So your comment is wrong and misleading - the form object _is_ a DOM object - the `submit` method would still have been clobbered by calling the submit button submit. I've tested your solution on chrome and FF and it produces the same error as OPs code

Comment: @tobyodavies - well corrected. i've removed my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the button is named submit and hs id submit.  Change that and it works.
You overwrote submit function with a submit button element.

Comment: I just discovered the correct answer and it is exactly what you said, I had to get rid of the name and the id attributes in the input tag with type="submit"

Answer (score 2):

This would work if you hadn't `name`ed your submit button `submit` this clobbers the method definition

Comment: Could anyone actually  post the correct code example, the answers are very confusing.

Comment: Change `<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit />` to `<input type="submit" name="anything-other-than-submit" id="anything-other-than-submit" />` - the name and ID being "submit: caused the input DOM element to overwrite the form DOM element's submit method, making it impossible to submit programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

try this one..

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is the title</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function Test() {
            document.getElementById("input1").value="NewValue1";
            document.getElementById("input2").value="NewValue2";
            document.getElementById('form').submit();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Test();">
<form method="post" name="form" id="form" action="new.html">
    <label for="input1">Input1</label> <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text"/>
    <label for="input2">Input2</label> <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text"/>
    <input name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```